# Where are menu items to activate extensions in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed a few markdown preview extensions to try. I assumed that when I was editing a markdown document they would be available as context menu items or one of the top manue. I don't see them anywhere.

**Edit**
One of the three is showing up as a context menu if I click inside the document. Could they just be blocking each other?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + P opens a command prompt where you can search for your extensions' commands